# How to make timeseries line and hist graph in the same level with ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make this kind of graph in ggplot2 R.
[Plot timeseries and hist in same row but different data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfulZ.png)

I wrote some code but the multiplot function split the graph in two equal size.
I take the multiplot function from this website: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

```
     gPreci10 <- ggplot(Preci_Ure_25010060, aes(x = Fecha, y = Valor))+
      annotate("rect", fill="green", alpha = 0.2,
               xmin= c(as.Date("1984-05-01"),as.Date("2000-04-14")), 
               xmax = c(as.Date("1998-05-01"), as.Date("2010-05-13")),
               ymin = c(-Inf,-Inf), 
               ymax = c(Inf,Inf)) +
     geom_line(na.rm = TRUE,color = 'blue') +
     ggtitle("Precipitación diaria Estación Uré") +
     xlab("Año") + ylab("Precipitación (mm)") +
     (scale_x_date(limits=fIniFin,
                    breaks=date_breaks("2 year"),
                    labels=date_format("%Y")))+
     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))

    gHist1 <- ggplot(Preci_Ure_25010060, aes(x=Valor))+
      geom_histogram(na.rm = TRUE, fill = "skyblue", alpha=0.5)+
      theme_minimal()+
      coord_fixed(ratio.values / ratio.display)

multiplot(gPreci10,gHist1,cols=2)
```

This is the graph I get using the code.
[Timeseries plor and hist with ggplot2 and multiplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hazlp.png)

If someone can help me, I will be grateful

Comment: `multiplot` is an old function, created before a number of packages were created with support for multiple plot layouts. Here's one option: `library(gridExtra); grid.arrange(gPreci10, gHist1, ncol=2, widths=c(5,2))`

Comment: Another option is `plot_grid()` from the `cowplot` package. Also, a newer package called `patchwork` is available on github. See the [vignette](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) for installation and a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eip10, the patchwork is what I looking for